# Visual studio 2015, Where is network usage while debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015 enterprise, my application is primarily a network application, that sends and receives data from the network.

In the diagnostics window in VS that shows up while debugging I can see CPU/Events but there is no Newtork usage.

Is it even available in VS, I thought that was a very basic thing in professional IDE's nowadays ?

Thanks,
Ahmed

Comment: What IDE have you seen that has this feature? None that I've seen (other than those built into webbrowsers) offer this *basic thing*.

Comment: it is present in xcode

Comment: Ah, got it. You've seen it once, and that makes it a *very basic thing in professional IDEs*.

Comment: You see a question mark at the end ?? perhaps when you are out of sarcastic mode you will notice it is only a question.

Comment: Wow. Someone has no sense of humor. To be clear, a *basic feature* is something that almost everything includes. A telephone has the *basic feature* of the user being able to dial phone numbers, and a phone missing that *basic feature* would be notable. A *basic feature* for an automobile is that it has a way to steer it when going down the road. That you've seen a single IDE that implements a feature does not make it a *basic feature* that every other IDE must include or criticized for not doing so.

Comment: XCode is not the only IDE, Android studio also has this feature I hope you are somewhat aware of how much development share nowadays goes to iphone and android development, when doing mobile development this is hugely important and VS2015 also features cross platform mobile applications, they've recently purchased xamarin. Basic features have context and what is known to be basic evolves overtime. To be able send an email from mobile is now a basic thing, this wasn't true a decade ago, still I am not claiming anything, all I had put was an innocent question, ..